# UIVisualEffectView not setting to nil

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiblureffect

I have a UIVisualEffectView that I am trying to set to nil upon viewdidload

What am I doing wrong?

```
@IBOutlet var popUpView: UIView!

@IBOutlet weak var visualEffectView: UIVisualEffectView!

var effect: UIVisualEffect!

@IBOutlet weak var headerLabel: UILabel!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    effect = visualEffectView.effect
    self.visualEffectView.effect = nil
    popUpView.layer.cornerRadius = 5

}
```

Comment: print(self.visualEffectView.effect) and see if it is nil

Comment: @3stud1ant3 when I print it out it is not nil

Comment: I tried this and it gives me nil , I have tried this code: @IBOutlet weak var myVisualEffectView: UIVisualEffectView!
        var effect: UIVisualEffect!
        override func viewDidLoad() {
                super.viewDidLoad()
                effect = myVisualEffectView.effect
                print(effect)
                self.myVisualEffectView.effect = nil
                print(self.myVisualEffectView.effect)
                
        } , first print(effect) prints the UIBlur effect instance and second print prints nil

Comment: OK, I can make mine print nil but for some reason the visualeffectview still shows up

Comment: You want to remove the effect and then again use it at other place or you just simply want to remove it?

Comment: remove and then use it again when a certain button is clicked

Comment: I have used blureffect of visualeffect but you can use any. Please change it. see my answer

Answer (score 0):

```
    See my answer


    var blurEffect = UIBlurEffect()
    var blurview : UIView = UIView()

    //HERE pass view as bringtofront from blurview and pass view where you want to set blurview upon
        func add_blur_view(v : UIView, view_bring_to_front: UIView) {
            blurEffect  = UIBlurEffect(style: UIBlurEffectStyle.dark)
            let blurEffectView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: blurEffect)
            blurEffectView.frame = v.bounds
            blurEffectView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
            v.addSubview(blurEffectView)
            v.bringSubview(toFront: view_bring_to_front)
        }

        func remove_blur_view(v : UIView)  {
            for subview in v.subviews {
                if subview is UIVisualEffectView {
                    subview.removeFromSuperview()
                }
            }
        }
```